# Unable to clean intsall

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have downloaded an ISO file of Ubuntu 12.10 x86 from the official website (www.ubuntu.com). When I tried to install it, everything was going good until I got the error message something like `The media you are using is probably corrupt or you have a hard disk error.` It did't tell me what to do.

I'm already running Windows 7 Ultimate on my PC and it's running fine. I have tested my hard disk for error and no errors were found by **System Mechanic Pro 11**. After that, I  tried to install my Windows 7 on the same partition and it was successful.

Even now I am unable to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try to re-download and re-burn your Ubuntu ISO. It seems like it got messed up in the process.

This time, try reading the **[How To MD5 Sum](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM)** article to verify that the download was successful.

The expected output for 12.04 32 bit should be:

```
e235b63c02644e219b7bf3668f479c9e *ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```

---

Excerpt:

> First open a terminal and go to the correct directory to check a downloaded iso file:
>
> ```
> ubuntu@ubuntu-desktop:~$ cd Downloads
> ```
>
> Linux is case sensitive so "Downloads" is NOT "downloads".
>
> Then run the following command from within the download directory.
>
> ```
> md5sum ubuntu-11.10-dvd-i386.iso
> ```
>
> `md5sum` should then print out a single line after calculating the hash:
>
> ```
> 8044d756b7f00b695ab8dce07dce43e5 ubuntu-11.10-dvd-i386.iso
> ```